# Nested values copies from one object to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a nodejs code that copies values from one object (submitted from a firm) to a model object.

Model:

```
var directory_model = {

    "link_title": {
        "value": 1, // This needs to be filled with object data
        "validation": null
    },

    "link_desc": {
        "value": 2, // This needs to be filled with object data
        "validation": null
    },
};
```

Object values that must get into the model:

```
   { link_title: 'test1', link_desc: 'test2' }
```

Here is the code that does, it with lodash. This code does the job:

```
_.forOwn(directory_model, function(directory_model_value, directory_model_key) {
    _.forOwn(fields, function(fields_value, fields_key) {
        "use strict";
        if (directory_model_key === fields_key)  {
            directory_model[directory_model_key].value = fields_value;
        }
    });

});
```

I don't like the nested loop, and would like to know if you know another way to do this.
I found several ways, but none of them works, because of the nested properties.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with libraries? This doesn't need anything more than pure JS. Assuming the incoming data is stored in `fields`:

```js
var keys = Object.keys(fields);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if(directory_model[key]) {
        directory_model[key].value = fields[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

If you are not sure that your `fields` (form i guess) contains only keys that exist in `directory_model`, I recommend assigning the values in one iteration, with a simple check:

```
_.forOwn(fields, function (fields_value, fields_key) {
    if (directory_model[fields_key]) {
        directory_model[fields_key].value = fields_value;
    }
});
```